# Parse jsonarray?

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, qtcore

I've got an JSON like the following:

```
{
    "agentsArray": [{
        "ID": 570,
        "picture": "03803.png",
        "name": "Bob"
    }, {
        "ID": 571,
        "picture": "02103.png",
        "name": "Tina"
    }]
}
```

Now I'm trying to loop through each array element. Using the `qt-json` library https://github.com/da4c30ff/qt-json

Tried:

```
            foreach(QVariantMap plugin, result["agentsArray"].toList()) {
                qDebug() << "  -" << plugin["ID"].toString();
            }
```

But cannot get it to work, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Qt 4 or 5? Qt 5 has json parser classes in QtCore.

Comment: That would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would recommend using the QJson* classes from QtCore in Qt 5. They are very efficient due to the machine readable binary storage optimized for reading and writing, and it is also very convenient to use them due to the nice API they have.

This code base works for me just fine, but please note that I neglected all the error checking for now which is not a good advice for production code. This is just a prototype code, respectively.

#### main.json

```
{
    "agentsArray": [{
        "ID": 570,
        "picture": "03803.png",
        "name": "Bob"
    }, {
        "ID": 571,
        "picture": "02103.png",
        "name": "Tina"
    }]
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QFile file("main.json");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QByteArray jsonData = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData);
    QJsonObject object = document.object();

    QJsonValue value = object.value("agentsArray");
    QJsonArray array = value.toArray();
    foreach (const QJsonValue & v, array)
        qDebug() << v.toObject().value("ID").toInt();

    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
570 
571
```

Answer (score 0):

`output` is QByteArray type

```
QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(output));

foreach (const QJsonValue & v, doc.array()){
  Person person;
  person.fromJson(v.toObject());
}
```