# Parse unnamed JSON Array from a web service in Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, c++11, qt5.10

I am trying to parse this JSON from a web service.

```
  [
      {
        "word": "track",
        "score": 4144
      },
      {
        "word": "trail",
        "score": 2378
      },
      {
        "word": "domestic dog",
        "score": 51
      },
      {
        "word": "dogiron"
      }
  ]
```

When I log out the response from the API call as a QString as below, it comes out fine but with all quotes escaped, thus not making it a valid JSON:

```
QString response = (QString) data->readAll();
qDebug() << "Return data: \n" << response;
```

Examples I have seen so far (e.g. [Parse jsonarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174393/parse-jsonarray)) only parse named arrays which they grab from a `QJsonObject` by name. Any hints on how to use `QJsonArray` directly or together with `QJsonDocument::fromJson()` on the return data?

Comment: Also, you are seeing quotes escaped in your sample code because `QDebug` is escaping them in its output. It does not mean the escape characters are present in the QString.

Comment: That part I get as quotes in a string are expected to be escaped for proper output. My point in that case is that I can't use `QString` as valid JSON array to iterate through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QJsonDocument` has a member called [`array()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#array) that returns the `QJsonArray` contained in the document.

For example:

```
QFile file("main.json");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QByteArray jsonData = file.readAll();
file.close();

QJsonParseError parseError;
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData, &parseError);

if (parseError.error != QJsonParseError::NoError)
{
    qDebug() << "Parse error: " << parseError.errorString();
    return;
}

if (!document.isArray())
{
    qDebug() << "Document does not contain array";
    return;
}

QJsonArray array = document.array();

foreach (const QJsonValue & v, array)
{
    QJsonObject obj = v.toObject();
    qDebug() << obj.value("word").toString();
    QJsonValue score = obj.value("score");
    if (!score.isUndefined())
        qDebug() << score.toInt();
}
```

Comment: And `isArray()` to check whether the document is an array.

Comment: I tried 
`QJsonDocument jsdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response);
qDebug() << "size: " << jsdoc.array().size(); // but this returns 'size: 0'.`

Comment: Try passing a `QJsonParseError` object to `fromJson` to find out if it is hitting a parsing error, and checking `document.isArray()` before fetching the size.

Comment: There is a parse error. I get '`Parse error:  "illegal value"`'

Comment: Then either the byte array contains invalid JSON to begin with or you are performing some bad transformation on it before parsing. I would inspect it in a debugger.

Comment: Doing `QString response = (QString) data->readAll();` was modifying the JSON because `data` was declared as a pointer. Fixed, now working; thanks a bunch.